# android adding value to sharedpreference string set from null

Tags: android, arrays, string, set, sharedpreferences

I am currently trying to save and retrieve array of string into the shared preference in my android apps. The problem is, I haven't add any string into my "set of string", so basically when I tried to retrieve it, it will return null. The problem is, after I get the Set of string, I want to add a string to the set. But it shows error that I can't add a string to a null object. Can someone help me? thanks..

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> setId = pref.getStringSet("id", null);
setId.add("admin");

Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("id", setId);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just return an empty implementation of [Set](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html) as your default value. For example, an empty ArraySet should work fine:

```
Set<String> setId = pref.getStringSet("id", new ArraySet<>());
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually i've tried that before, and the IDE ask me to cast the arraylist into set, but when I do, it also shows error that arraylist cannot be converted into set. And if i try to add empty implementation of new Set<String> it also implements a lot of methods of the set that i dont think is needed.

Comment: I have ArrayLists on the brain, ArraySet is what you're looking for. Edited answer to fix the mistake

Comment: ArraySet is only available after API 23, so you might want to use HashSet if you need to be backward-compatible. Hopefully at some point there will be a support library implementation of ArraySet like there is with ArrayMap.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> setId = pref.getStringSet("id", null); 
    //The second argument 'null' means if there is no value for key "id", it will return null
    if(setId == null){
        setId = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    setId.add("admin");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("id", setId);
    editor.commit();
```